# Box2D / OpenGL : one texture mapped on many vertices

Tags: c++, objective-c, opengl, box2d, texture-mapping

I'm trying to do this kind of object with Box2D : [Wobbly Picture using Box2D](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cT6ZM3KkqY)

Building the grid with bodies and joints is not a problem, but I would like to use this matrix of points to warp my image. the problem is that I don't know how to "cut" my texture and map it on an OpenGL vertex array. I heard about u and v coordinates, but what about the texture cropping ?

Comment: What have you tried? What about texture cropping? It shouldn't happen with correct texture coordinates

Comment: Now, come on. How do you want to implement something complex, if you don't know basics? Any opengl tutorial about textures explains texture coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asking how to connect textures, take a look into this modification of [this hane lesson](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/) :

```
//
// This code was created by Jeff Molofee '99 (ported to Linux/GLUT by Richard Campbell '99)
//
// If you've found this code useful, please let me know.
//
// Visit me at www.demonews.com/hosted/nehe
// (email Richard Campbell at ulmont@bellsouth.net)
//
#include <GL/glut.h>    // Header File For The GLUT Library
#include <GL/gl.h>  // Header File For The OpenGL32 Library
#include <GL/glu.h> // Header File For The GLu32 Library
#include <stdio.h>      // Header file for standard file i/o.
#include <stdlib.h>     // Header file for malloc/free.
#include <unistd.h>     // needed to sleep.

/* ascii code for the escape key */
#define ESCAPE 27

/* The number of our GLUT window */
int window;

/* floats for x rotation, y rotation, z rotation */
float xrot, yrot, zrot;

/* storage for one texture  */
int texture[1];

/* Image type - contains height, width, and data */
struct Image {
    unsigned long sizeX;
    unsigned long sizeY;
    char *data;
};
typedef struct Image Image;

// quick and dirty bitmap loader...for 24 bit bitmaps with 1 plane only.
// See http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/~mxr/gfx/2d/BMP.txt for more info.
int ImageLoad(char *filename, Image *image) {
    FILE *file;
    unsigned long size;                 // size of the image in bytes.
    unsigned long i;                    // standard counter.
    unsigned short int planes;          // number of planes in image (must be 1)
    unsigned short int bpp;             // number of bits per pixel (must be 24)
    char temp;                          // temporary color storage for bgr-rgb conversion.

    // make sure the file is there.
    if ((file = fopen(filename, "rb"))==NULL)
    {
    printf("File Not Found : %s\n",filename);
    return 0;
    }

    // seek through the bmp header, up to the width/height:
    fseek(file, 18, SEEK_CUR);

    // read the width
    if ((i = fread(&image->sizeX, 4, 1, file)) != 1) {
    printf("Error reading width from %s.\n", filename);
    return 0;
    }
    printf("Width of %s: %lu\n", filename, image->sizeX);

    // read the height
    if ((i = fread(&image->sizeY, 4, 1, file)) != 1) {
    printf("Error reading height from %s.\n", filename);
    return 0;
    }
    printf("Height of %s: %lu\n", filename, image->sizeY);

    // calculate the size (assuming 24 bits or 3 bytes per pixel).
    size = image->sizeX * image->sizeY * 3;

    // read the planes
    if ((fread(&planes, 2, 1, file)) != 1) {
    printf("Error reading planes from %s.\n", filename);
    return 0;
    }
    if (planes != 1) {
    printf("Planes from %s is not 1: %u\n", filename, planes);
    return 0;
    }

    // read the bpp
    if ((i = fread(&bpp, 2, 1, file)) != 1) {
    printf("Error reading bpp from %s.\n", filename);
    return 0;
    }
    if (bpp != 24) {
    printf("Bpp from %s is not 24: %u\n", filename, bpp);
    return 0;
    }

    // seek past the rest of the bitmap header.
    fseek(file, 24, SEEK_CUR);

    // read the data.
    image->data = (char *) malloc(size);
    if (image->data == NULL) {
    printf("Error allocating memory for color-corrected image data");
    return 0;
    }

    if ((i = fread(image->data, size, 1, file)) != 1) {
    printf("Error reading image data from %s.\n", filename);
    return 0;
    }

    for (i=0;i<size;i+=3) { // reverse all of the colors. (bgr -> rgb)
    temp = image->data[i];
    image->data[i] = image->data[i+2];
    image->data[i+2] = temp;
    }

    // we're done.
    return 1;
}

// Load Bitmaps And Convert To Textures
void LoadGLTextures() {
    // Load Texture
    Image *image1;

    // allocate space for texture
    image1 = (Image *) malloc(sizeof(Image));
    if (image1 == NULL) {
    printf("Error allocating space for image");
    exit(0);
    }

    if (!ImageLoad("Data/lesson6/NeHe.bmp", image1)) {
    exit(1);
    }

    // Create Texture
    glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);   // 2d texture (x and y size)

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); // scale linearly when image bigger than texture
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); // scale linearly when image smalled than texture

    // 2d texture, level of detail 0 (normal), 3 components (red, green, blue), x size from image, y size from image,
    // border 0 (normal), rgb color data, unsigned byte data, and finally the data itself.
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, image1->sizeX, image1->sizeY, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image1->data);
};

/* A general OpenGL initialization function.  Sets all of the initial parameters. */
void InitGL(int Width, int Height)          // We call this right after our OpenGL window is created.
{
    LoadGLTextures();               // Load The Texture(s)
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);            // Enable Texture Mapping
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   // Clear The Background Color To Blue
    glClearDepth(1.0);              // Enables Clearing Of The Depth Buffer
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);           // The Type Of Depth Test To Do
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);            // Enables Depth Testing
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);            // Enables Smooth Color Shading

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();               // Reset The Projection Matrix

    gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)Width/(GLfloat)Height,0.1f,100.0f);   // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

/* The function called when our window is resized (which shouldn't happen, because we're fullscreen) */
void ReSizeGLScene(int Width, int Height)
{
    if (Height==0)              // Prevent A Divide By Zero If The Window Is Too Small
    Height=1;

    glViewport(0, 0, Width, Height);        // Reset The Current Viewport And Perspective Transformation

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(45.0f,(GLfloat)Width/(GLfloat)Height,0.1f,100.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

/* The main drawing function. */
void DrawGLScene()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);     // Clear The Screen And The Depth Buffer
    glLoadIdentity();               // Reset The View

    glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-5.0f);              // move 5 units into the screen.
    glRotatef(xrot,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);   // choose the texture to use.

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 0.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);
    glTexCoord2f(0.5f, 1.0f); glVertex3f( 0.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f);

    glEnd();                                    // done with the polygon.

    xrot += 0.004;

    // since this is double buffered, swap the buffers to display what just got drawn.
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* Initialize GLUT state - glut will take any command line arguments that pertain to it or
       X Windows - look at its documentation at http://reality.sgi.com/mjk/spec3/spec3.html */
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    /* Select type of Display mode:
     Double buffer
     RGBA color
     Alpha components supported
     Depth buffer */
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH);

    /* get a 640 x 480 window */
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);

    /* the window starts at the upper left corner of the screen */
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);

    /* Open a window */
    window = glutCreateWindow("Jeff Molofee's GL Code Tutorial ... NeHe '99");

    /* Register the function to do all our OpenGL drawing. */
    glutDisplayFunc(&DrawGLScene);

    /* Even if there are no events, redraw our gl scene. */
    glutIdleFunc(&DrawGLScene);

    /* Register the function called when our window is resized. */
    glutReshapeFunc(&ReSizeGLScene);

    /* Initialize our window. */
    InitGL(640, 480);

    /* Start Event Processing Engine */
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Specifically, into the `DrawGLScene()` function, where I split the quad into 2 pieces, and take a note about texture coordinates.